# How do you format money but allow negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this awesome function to format money as users enter it, however I can't seem to figure out how to accept negative values.

```
$(this).on('change click keyup input paste', 'input.dollar', function() {
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace(/(?!\.)\D/g, "").replace(/(?:\..*)\./g, "").replace(/\.(\d\d)\d?$/, '.$1').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. Maybe not the best way to do it though.

```
$(this).on('change click keyup input paste', 'input.dollar', function() {
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        var sign = value.charAt(0),
        $return = 0;
        $return = value.replace(/(?!\.)\D/g, "").replace(/(?:\..*)\./g, "").replace(/\.(\d\d)\d?$/, '.$1').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        if (sign == '-')
        {
            $return = '-'+$return;
        }

        return $return;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more understandable example:

```js
(Number(''.replace('1','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"$0.00"

(Number('1'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"$1.00"

(Number('10'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"$10.00"

(Number('100'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"$100.00"

(Number('1000'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"$1,000.00"

(Number('-1000'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"-$1,000.00"

(Number('-1000.09'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"-$1,000.09"

(Number('$-1,000.09'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"-$1,000.09"

(Number('-$1,000.09'.replace('$','').replace(',','')))
  .toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
"-$1,000.09"
```

Comment: Why are you replacing `1` in the first example. Is that a typo?